# Is an object pointer in a vector deleted if I call delete on the object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, vector

Recently, I was confused on why I continuously was faced with a segmentation fault trying to access an element in a `vector` of pointers of certain objects. I didn't manage to resolve the issue, but I suspect that it is because after I pushed the object pointer into a `vector`, I called `delete` on it, thinking that the `vector` stored a copy.

In the following code:

```
std::vector<SomeObject *> testvector;
SomeObject * testobject = new SomeObject(/* some arguments here, call constructor */)
testvector.push_back(testobject);
delete testobject; // does this affect the element in the vector?
```

The debugger confirms that the pointers getting added to the vector do indeed have proper data, but once I call delete on them, I'm unsure if the element inside the vector is affected. Does the vector store just a copy? When I call delete on the object, I suspect that delete is being called on the pointer in the vector, but I am unsure.

Now I tried to print out the data in the vector after calling delete, I get this: ??? ?? ???? ???

And I am assuming that the call to delete has affected the vector element. Is this the case? I thought that after I added the pointer to the vector, I could safely free the object without affecting the element in the vector, but it seems that I end up accessing memory that is no longer allocated. Does the call to delete affect the pointer in the vector?

Comment: This is why you don't store raw pointers in vectors, then you don't have to worry what happens to the people that do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Does the call to delete affect the pointer in the vector?"*

It doesn't affect the pointer. It affects the behavior invoked by using this pointer since the object it points to no longer exists. When you call `delete`, the object is deleted and whatever you try to do with that object using invalid (old, dangling) pointer, the ***behavior is undefined***.

```
std::vector<SomeObject *> testvector;
SomeObject * testobject = new SomeObject()
testvector.push_back(testobject);
```

Constructs a vector of pointers, creates an instace of `SomeObject` and pushes an address of this object to your vector. Then when you call:

```
delete testobject;
```

There is no way how `std::vector` could know that the object has been deleted. Your vector still contains an old pointer, which has became invalid by the time the object was deleted. A possible solution could be using a vector of ***smart pointers*** such as `shared_ptr`, ***however*** at first you should ***consider whether you want to use a vector of pointers at first place***. Maybe `std::vector<SomeObject>` would be more reasonable way to go.

Comment: So since the vector holds only the addresses of the objects, calling delete on them "invalidates" that address, and the pointer is no longer valid?

Comment: @Ra1nMaster: Yes. What is stored at that memory is destructed and the memory is freed, but in the vector you still keep an address of this memory regardless whether the `delete` has been called or not.

Comment: (I have to use the vector of pointers because the class is an abstract base class with several child classes.)

Answer (score 1):

The vector contains pointers not the objects theirself. So after deleting an object the corresponding pointer will be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both `testobject` and the inserted element into the vector are pointing to a same address. After deleting one of them another will be a dangling pointer and dereferencing it is *undefined behavior*.

You can use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>> testvector;
std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> testobject(new SomeObject);
testvector.push_back(testobject);
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> testvector;
std::unique_ptr<int> testobject(new SomeObject);
testvector.push_back(std::move(testobject));
// After `std::move` you can not use `testobject` anymore!
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about std::move, that seems practical since I wouldn't need to use the pointer after using push_back. But I think I'll stick with not calling delete at all, to keep the memory allocated, which was my original intent.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a pointer, you only copy the address of the object, not the object itself. That means the pointer in your vector and your pointer outside the vector were still referring to the same thing when you called delete.

The reason the debugger may still have shown seemingly valid data is because the memory doesn't necessarily get overwritten when you delete something. It's simply marked as 'free' so that it can be used by something else later if required.